# Other ways of calling dispatchEvents without using xml schema in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I wanted to know if there are ways to use dispatchEvents with custom event function calls without actually instantiate the function in an xml form but doing so in the script. What I am trying to do is, have a developer use my custom component button, but add his/her own function to what is already added to my own click event call. so just as a case he/she wants to add there own validation function of that click event. One way i have it is where i create an instance in my component within the xml schema. example, I have it where:

i have a mxml component called DialogWindow.mxml and inside I have

```
  <mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="cancBtnClick", type="flash.events.Event")]
    [Event(name="okBtnClick", type="flash.events.Event")]
  </mx:Metadata>
```

and in my script in DialogWindow.mxml i created a button with a click event called cancelAction(event);

```
  _buttonCancel = new Button();
  _buttonCancel.label = "Cancel";
  _buttonCancel.addEventListener("click", cancelAction);
  _buttonCancel.enabled = true;
```

In the "cancelAction" function I add the dispatchEvent to cancBtnClick as this will be the userdefined function.

```
  protected function cancelAction(event:Event):void {
dispatchEvent(new Event("cancBtnClick"));
PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
  }
```

When deriving the component DialogWindow.mxml from another component, I can use this statement where myFunction is taken place of cancBtnClick in cancelAction function.

```
  // from TestButton.mxml
  <cmp:DialogWindow cancBthClick="myFunction()" />
```

The above works fine, but what if i want to call it using derived class call in a script. such as

```
  public var dialogW:IFlexDisplayObject = null; 
  (dialogW as DialogWindow).cancBtnClick = "myFunction"; // this is an instance of DialogWindow
```

When trying this, of course there is no cancBtnClick. So i know i am not implementing this correctly. If you know how I can change my code so i can do the above. I would be greatly appreciative. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
(dialogW as DialogWindow).addEventListener("cancBtnClick", yourFunction);

public function yourFunction(event:Event):void {
  // handle the event.
}
```

It's good practice to also remove the listener when you are done.

```
(dialogW as DialogWindow).removeEventListener("cancBtnClick", yourFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DialogWindow you can define property

```
public function set cancBtnClick(func : Function) : void
{
    addEventListener("cancBtnClick", func);
}
```

And then use it as you wish

```
(dialogW as DialogWindow).cancBtnClick = myFunction;
```

Hope, it will help you.